# User input path psftp script batch file

Tags: command-line, batch-file, ftp, cmd

I am trying to implement a scenerio like the user should give a path and the path should be binded to another .

bat file and that path should be the destination where am going to put my file from local.

My code looks like this:

- Getfile.bat:

  ```
  set /P INPUT=Type input: 
  psftp <user>@<IP> -b D:\FileTransfer.bat -pw <PW>
  ```
- Filetransfer.bat:

  ```
  cd %INPUT% 
  lcd d:\ 
  put log.sh
  ```

> Error :Access denied Remote working directory is /home/irisuser Directory /home/irisuser/%INPUT%: no such file or directory

Comment: give us data, which you enter to INPUT.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `%INPUT%` is not passed to `Filetransfer.bat`. If you want `psftp` to `cd` into a user-defined directory, you have to create `Filetransfer.bat` on the fly:

```
set /P INPUT=Type input: 

>D:\Filetransfer.bat echo.cd %INPUT%
>>D:\Filetransfer.bat echo.lcd d:\
>>D:\Filetransfer.bat echo.put log.sh

psftp <user>@<IP> -b D:\FileTransfer.bat -pw <PW>
```